# Pegar valor JSON retornado do Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel-5.4

Tenho o seguinte `JSON` retornado de um `controller` `Laravel`:

```
{
  "id": 105,
  "tratamento_id": "24",
  "eim": null,
  "oft": "12",
  "codigo_produto": "CO009-1200-1200",
  "descricao_produto": "COMPENSADO 9X1200X1200  ",
  "tipo_mercadoria": "2",
  "comprimento": "2",
  "largura": "2",
  "espessura": "2",
  "quantidade": ".0000",
  "m3_unitario": "2.0000",
  "m3_total": "2.0000",
  "estufa": "0",
  "nfe": "2",
  "kit": "1",
  "kit_id": null
}
```

porém no `javascript` não consigo pegar o valor do `id`, segue o código com os testes que fiz:

```
$.post(URL+'/json/remover_item_kit',{
    _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    id: $("#id_item_kit_delete").val()
}).done(function(data){

    console.log("1 :" + data.id);
    console.log("2 :" + data[0].id);
    console.log("3 :" + data["id"]);
    console.log("4 :" + data[0]["id"]);
});
```

segue os resultados:

```
1 :undefined
2 :undefined
3 :undefined
4 :undefined
```

eu precisava acessar as propriedades do data porém não obtive sucesso.

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof data, data);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por um simples detalhes, faltou passar o quarto paramento que significa o tipo de retorno que no caso é um `json`, [como especificado na documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), ***exemplo***:

> `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

ou seja, o [dataType](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType) pode ser:

> `xml, json, script, text e html`

As alterações, foram feitas inclusive no recebimento da função de sucesso, ***exemplo***:

```
$.post(URL+'/json/remover_item_kit',
  {
       _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(), 
       id: $("#id_item_kit_delete").val()
  }, 
  function(data)
  {
      console.log(data.id);
  }, 'json');
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- [jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType)

Comment: Show de bola funcionou, também encontrei um outra solução adicionando isso inicio da função done data = JSON.parse(data);